# Java: Object.wait() causes main thread of execution to return from test

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm in the process of writing some tests to drive development for a side project of mine, and am encountering some **very strange Java behavior**:

**Object.wait() causes the main thread of execution to return and skip all of the following lines of execution, but only the second time it's called in a loop.**

The reason I know this is because I'm attempting to write tests without the use of Thread.sleep() because I believe it is generally bad practice to insert these in main threads of execution, especially tests which would later scale and become extremely long-running tasks.

**Here is my test**:

```
@Test
  public void testSendReceiveAll() throws Exception {
    for (String s : (ArrayList<String>)testFiles) {
      ((FakeSendFileApi) sendFileApi).setSender(new InetSocketAddress(LOCALHOST,
          LOCALPORT)).setIncomingFileName(s + incrAppend());
      PendingFile pendingFile = new PendingFile(TEST_PATH + s, new InetSocketAddress(LOCALHOST,
          LOCALPORT));
      SendAction sendAction = new SendAction(pendingFile);
      Thread sendActionThread = new Thread(sendAction);
      synchronized (sendAction){
        sendActionThread.start();
        sendAction.wait(TIMEOUT_MS);
      }

      File file = new File(s + fileAppend);
      assertTrue(file.exists());
      assertTrue(file.isFile());
      assertTrue(file.canRead());
      assertTrue(file.delete());
    }
  }
```

**Explanation of what it does**: Iterate over all of the test files and send and receive them all locally.  There is a SendAction class which is instantiated and run in the test:

```
/**
   * Attempts to send the specified file to the specified <code>InetSocketAddress</code>.
   * The file's path must be specified completely either absolutely or relatively.
   *
   * @return true if <code>pendingFile</code> was sent successfully in its entirety.
   */
  public synchronized void run() {
    try {
      ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(pendingFile.getSender().getPort());
      serverSocket.setSoTimeout(socketTimeoutMillis);
      // Blocks until a connection is made on specified socket or until TIMEOUT is reached.
      Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
      System.out.println("Sending file " + pendingFile.getFileName());
      OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
      sendByteArray(new RandomAccessFile(pendingFile.getFileName(), "r"), outputStream);
      serverSocket.close();
      notifyAll();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println(e); // TODO log error appropriately
    }
  }
```

**The problem**: When I hit the synchronized block of the test, and start the thread to send, then wait for a notify from that sendAction, this works the first time in the loop.  **The second time through however**, the test simply passes and exits on the call to

```
sendAction.wait(TIMEOUT_MS);
```

This only occurs sometimes, and not others.  I have put print statements to see if I can achieve the race condition without debugging and it does send and receive the first file, but doesn't always send and receive the second file.  When I put a println() statement just after the sendAction.wait(TIMEOUT_MS); call, it never executes after the second loop iteration.

What gives???

Comment: I don't see you closing socket or its stream in run().

Comment: Your method surely doesn't *return* after executing that `wait`. It *completes abruptly*, throwing an exception. Better find out what that exception is. Otherwise, if there's no exception, then it just goes on executing those assert statements.

Comment: BTW in case of any exception in the child thread, you've got a deadlock (timing out eventually, in your case). You should `notifyAll` in `finally`.

Comment: And, needless to say, you are using `wait` against its contract. You must always implement the *wait loop* idiom.

Comment: @JohnTangBoyland: The socket.close() method actually closes and releases all associated channels from what I understand. (I can certainly try verbosely closing all associated objects.)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik : There is no exception being thrown.  Also great call on putting a finally clause in the try statement. As for spurious wakes, I was aware of them but under the impression that they were exceedingly rare, so I didn't bother to worry about them. I will insert some logic to try to account for this case. Thanks!

Comment: OK.  my worry is not the problem, but @MarkTopolnik's guess about exceptions seems very plausible.  You say that putting a print statement immediately after the wait() doesn't get executed?  That really sound like an exception.  Can you show the code you used to determine if an exception is thrown?

Comment: Also, your code should use "join" rather than "wait" if it intends to wait until the thread is done.

Comment: @JohnTangBoyland I surrounded the offending code in the test with a try, catch(Exception e).  Plus, the entirety of run() is surrounded by a try catch block, so shouldn't I be seeing the exception be thrown?  I will look into join() as an alternative. thanks!

Comment: If the println below the wait never executes, and there's no exception, then the remaining explanation is that wait never returns. The test framework may kill the entire subprocess running that test, upon realizing that the waiting thread is stuck.

Comment: We can see the try-catch-block in run.  We're asking about a try-catch-block in the main loop.  Just want to check that you put a try-catch there too, to be completely clear.

Comment: @JohnTangBoyland Correct, I placed a try-catch-block around my main loop and it has never caught an exception even when the final lines of the test are being skipped.

Comment: In general this is a bad idea, but for diagnosis, could you catch "Throwable" in the try-catch about the loop, print the stack trace, and then throw the exception again?

Comment: @JohnTangBoyland Well I did, and I still have the same strange random skipping of subsequent lines of code... Still at a loss of what exactly is going on here. It even happens if I attempt a .join() on the thread object instead.

Answer (score 1):

waits should always occur in loops. (Refer to javadoc of Object.wait() for more details).

Maintain a flag to mark the completion of the task and use it in the condition to guard sendAction.wait()

```
while(!sendAction.finished) {
    sendAction.wait(TIMEOUT_MS);
}
```

set "sendAction.finished" to true before calling the notifyAll()... AND DO THIS IN FINALLY.

Comment: While your answer is good advice in general, it is not the answer to this question. Spurious wake ups are not occurring as execution would resume after the wait() call if that were the case.